# How to do a pivot in pandas with duplicated entries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

How does one do a pivot in pandas? I can't around the 'duplicate entries' error. The input and the output should look like what is outlined below.

```
import pandas as pd

input = pd.DataFrame({'measure': ['length','length','length','weight','weight','weight','sex','sex','sex'],
                      'species': [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
                      'value': [1, 2, 3, 13, 45, 123, 0, 1, 1],
                      'set': [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]})

output = pd.DataFrame({'set': [3,3,3],
                       'species': [10, 10, 10],
                       'length': [1, 2, 3],
                       'weight': [13, 45, 123],
                       'sex': [0, 1, 1]})

test = input.pivot(index='set',columns='measure', values='value')

print(test)
```

Comment: Are you looking for a groupby?

Comment: @Blue What is your expected output?

Comment: The expected output should be just like what is in 'output'. I am struggking to transform 'input' into 'output'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this situation, we usually resolve to `groupby().cumcount()` to get the new index:

```
indf['idx'] = indf.groupby('measure').cumcount()
(indf.pivot_table(index=['idx','species','set'], 
                 columns='measure', 
                 values='value')
     .reset_index(('species','set'))
)
```

Output:

```
measure  species  set  length  sex  weight
idx                                       
0             10    3       1    0      13
1             10    3       2    1      45
2             10    3       3    1     123
```

Comment: Good answer, just for curiosity, is there something like a reverse `cumsum`/`cumcount`. Because reading from the `docs` there's no parameter that refers to the order. The idea is to apply a function that does exactly the same as `cumcount` but beginning from the bottom to the top.

Comment: AFAIK there is none. Usually people would do: `df.iloc[::-1].cumsum()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I thought the same, or using `sort_values()` if an specific order is desired.

Comment: Your output is exactly what I am looking for but I cant seem to reproduce it however:

Comment: Is this what you are doing ? 
import pandas as pd

indf = pd.DataFrame({'measure': ['length','length','length','weight','weight','weight','sex','sex','sex'],
                      'species': [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10],
                      'value': [1, 2, 3, 13, 45, 123, 0, 1, 1],
                      'set': [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]})

indf['idx'] = indf.groupby('measure').cumcount()
(indf.pivot_table(index=['idx','species','set'], 
                  columns='measure', 
                  values='value')
 .reset_index(('species','set'))
)

print(indf)

Comment: No, the last line `indf.pivot_table(...)` is the expected output, i.e., `outdf=indf.pivot_table(...); print(outdf)`.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.